# PHP MongoDB find with UTF-8

Tags: php, mongodb, encoding

I have a textsearch with MongoDB that i use with PHP.

It works fine except special characters from the german language. e.g. the word "Törn".

So the characters "Ö", "Ü", "Ä", "ß" can't be found and i don't know why.

This is the json that will be generated for a search:

```
{"text":"waypoints","search":"T\u00f6rn","language":"de"}
```

I tried

```
utf8_encode(utf8_decode($searched));
```

and

```
mb_convert_encoding($searched, "UTF-8");
```

so far but none of them changed the result i get. In `$searched` the search string, in this case "Törn", will be saved.

This is my command for the textsearch:

```
$cursor = $this->db->command(array(
    "text" => "waypoints", 
    'search' => $searched,
    'language' => 'de'
));
```

How can i deal with these characters correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the `'language' => 'de'` part of the command, now it's working!

But i'm not able to give a reason why the language parameter chrushed this Query.